# Is there any way to invoke an external URI scheme?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, uri-scheme

Is there any way to start an application by using an (already registered) URI scheme from my extension's code?

I want to monitor something through background.js and start an app by URI scheme automatically

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Let's see if I understand you: there is an app that is already registered for some scheme (say, `steam:` for example) and you want to invoke that? Or you want to add a scheme for an external app that does not have a scheme yet?

Comment: Exactly. I have an app that is already registered and I want to start it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by appending an `iframe` to your background page.

Again with the Steam example:

```
var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
frame.src = "steam://open/main";
// Needs to be inserted into document to trigger load
document.body.appendChild(frame);
document.body.removeChild(frame);
```

Comment: I have only a background.js file, I do not have a html file. So, is it does not work?

Comment: Yes, it does, I tested before posting. Chrome makes a blank HTML document with your scripts inserted, that you can manipulate as usual with DOM methods. It's just not actually a visible document.